# How to use a component fromAngular (v7) in AngularJS (v1.6.10)?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am looking for a solution on how to use a component/module/library developed in **Angular (v7)** in **AngularJS (v1.6.10)**.

There are multiple examples available of making a hybrid app (*containing one app code in another app*). But I am looking for separate codebase for both the applications and exporting the component from *Angular (v7)* to be imported and downgrade as directive in *AngularJS (v1.6.10)* application.

Answer (score 3):

you are on the wrong path. Angular 2+ is successfor of AngularJS and the framework is completely rewritten.

Short answer: you can't and you shouldn't use